# Replacing analog potentiometer with digipot for DC motor speed control

Tags: arduino, potentiometer, digital-potentiometer

I have a device with a beefcake DC motor controller like this one: https://www.bodine-electric.com/products/dc-controls/filtered-pwm-dc-basic-speed-control-open-chassis/0780/

The speed is controlled with a 10k ohm pot. The spec sheet says 0-5V referenced to chassis common or 10k ohm pot. Strangely, I measured 7.5V across the pot terminals, so this might not be the correct sheet.

I'd like to replace the pot with something I can control from an Arduino. I've done a little research and found out about the wonderful world of digipots like https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MCP41HV31 or http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/686036.pdf

What considerations do I need to swap in a digipot in place of the current pot? What kind of isolation do I need between the computer/arduino and the motor controller? The controller is mains powered.

Comment: Why not use a DAC controlled by the Arduino? Or just the PWM + RC-filter

Comment: As far as I know, the voltage reference on the motor controller side may not be the same as the one that the arduino is operating at (it's specifically referenced in the datasheet as a substitute for the 10k pot: "Alternatively, an isolated 0–5 VDC signal may be connected to “S2” using “S1” as common.") I don't know how to interpret this. I was planning on powering the Arduino with its own power supply as I don't want to tinker with the controller board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the datasheet mentions an isolated signal, you could use an optocoupler from an arduino PWM output:

[image]

The cap smooths the PWM into a more "DC" voltage.

"+5" "out" and "gnd" on the right side of the circuit should be the three terminals of the existing pot.

Comment: Ahhh, I was just reading about RC filters too. Seems simple enough. Thanks for the diagram. I've never seen the PWM pin drawn like on the left though. Is V2 a separate power source from the Arduino? What's its role here? Does the PWM pin act like a sink when it's "off"? Sorry for the basic questions. My background is programming, not electronics.

Comment: V2 is just the symbol for "voltage source" in the schematic editor, so yeah, it represents your pin's output voltage, you don't need to add a power source. Yes, microcontroller pins can sink and source current (when configured as output). Usually a couple mA to a couple tens of mA.

Comment: Thanks. I tested the RC filter on its own (not hooked to the controller) to experiment with the Arduino and it works like a charm; I've got some opto isolators on the way.

Comment: Last question: how are the R1/R3 values chosen? I tried with a LED and a wall wart first and got some pretty steep voltage drops. What do I need to consider if the motor control circuit is at 7.5V?

Comment: From the point of view of the output, R1 and R3 are in series. The motor controller likes a 10kOhm pot, which has an output impedance of 0-5k depending on the wiper position, so you could use two 2k2 resistors for R1 and R2 which gives a maximum output impedance of 4k4. If you put a LED at the output, it will limit the voltage to the LED Vf, so yeah you won't see much. If you use a multimeter instead of the LED it'll work for testing. Note the "+5V" "GND" and "OUT" in my schematic correspond to the +,-, and wiper connections of the pot that's supposed to be connected to the controller.